# Android Draw arc on AppWidget

Tags: android, canvas, widget, android-appwidget

I want to make a widget with circular progress, but i am unable to use the normal method due to AppWidget restrictions. Here's my code from the widget part:

```
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = "Test Text";
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setARGB(255, 0, 160, 200);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(30);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    final RectF oval = new RectF();
    oval.set(0, 0, 50, 50);

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(70, 70, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    c.drawArc(oval, -90, 270, false, paint);

    views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imagewa1, bmp);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
```

I have added image view in xml:

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagewa1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

This is what i am trying to achieve:

[image]

And this is what i have achieved: :/

[image]

I have tried looking for it in github and other forums but couldn't find anything for widget, since the custom components don't work in appwidgets.

I also want to add animation to the arcs, so i have to skip the canvas method.

Any sort of help is appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: In other words you wana code ready to copy and paste.... Please at least try to understand what is going on... Oval r is 25...  Stroke width is 30...  And this is exactly what's you get...

Comment: @Selvin I didn't just ask for a readymade source code, i tried, failed, even pasted the code here. I am new to android programming thats why its a bit tricky for me to understand certain concepts. Tried changing the radius as u mentioned, still unable to achieve the goal. There is no need to be rude about it. We are here to learn, not to demotivate each other.

Comment: And arc is still so big? No! That is the first step... But you are still far away from what's you wana achieve.... Stop asking and do background, change color, draw thin oval first then the strong arc... Still you had to draw text or place textview over the imageview and set the text... Programming is not only using the libraries and copy and pasting.. Most of the time you have to think, read, search...

Comment: @Selvin that image is an earlier screenshot when i posted the question. I have tried changing the values. I took reference from [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and changed the attributes accordingly. It works well in main activity but i am unable to achieve the same behavior in widget. I did what i can, i have been trying this since 2 days. please don't mock people before knowing their knowledge level and the amount of work they have done before asking a question here.